# How to get Number of Docs for the index, using Recovery API

Tags: elasticsearch

I used to retrieve Number of Docs in the index using the below code in elasticsearch version 0.19

```
 private long getNumberOfDocuments(String indexName) {
     IndicesStatusResponse response =    
              client.admin().indices().prepareStatus(indexName).execute().actionGet();
        return response.getIndex(indexName).getDocs().getNumDocs();
 }
```

but as the IndiceStatusResponse is deprecated, I do not want to use it anymore, as suggested, I am looking to use RecoveryResponse, but not sure how can I get the number of docs using Recovery API.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

To get the the actual document count of index you  should  use the [count api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html).

The number of documents provided by [status](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-status.html#indices-status) actually counts nested documents as individual documents which is similar to what [indices stats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) api provides.

So in case you want the above *status* behavior you could use *indices stats* instead .

*Recovery Api* does not provide you this data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got confused about the usage, as the comments in DocStatus class mention that "This class will be removed in future versions, Use the recovery API instead"

Comment: Lucene has 2 billion document limit. Does this limit include the nested documents you mention?